# Why does the iMessage program throw a database error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imessage

I'm a beginner and I've tried creating a iMessage program that sends a single word from a song's lyrics until it reaches the end. Unfortunately, I have encountered an error that I don't understand a single bit. I have tried researching about the bug, but I only see posts about actual SQL, and I haven't used it before.

It only sends one message and then throws errors like these:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/levs/OneDrive/python/python-projects/14/messagebot.py", line 21, in <module>
    sendMessage("+44 7871579435", getLyrics())
  File "/Users/levs/OneDrive/python/python-projects/14/messagebot.py", line 18, in sendMessage
    imessage.send(phone, message)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py_imessage/imessage.py", line 16, in send
    db_conn.open()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py_imessage/db_conn.py", line 21, in open
    db = sqlite3.connect(db_path, uri=True)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

And this is the code:

```
from time import sleep
from py_imessage import imessage


def getLyrics():
    with open('lyrics.txt') as file:
        return ' '.join([str(line.strip()) for line in file])


def getWords(lyrics):
    return lyrics.split()


def sendMessage(phone, lyrics):
    for message in getWords(lyrics):
        imessage.send(phone, message)


sendMessage("+44 1122334455", getLyrics())
```

I would appreciate any kind of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research on the `py_imessage` package. It works by accessing the iMessages database on your Mac. The error message you are seeing,

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

basically means that your Mac is not allowing the program to access that database. To fix this issue, you will need to boot your Mac into Recovery Mode and run:

```
crsutil disable
```

in the terminal. This can be done by holding <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> when restarting your Mac. Once it boots into Recovery mode, go to Utilites > Terminal, and run `csrutil disable` there. Then you can type `reboot` and boot back into normal MacOS.